# Работа с таймером и текстовым полем в Qt. Исправить ошибки в приложении

Tags: c++, qt

Нужно, чтобы строка в текстовом поле опускалась, а затем поднималась на количество строк, заданное в QSpinBox, пока активен QCheckBox. Повесил все на один слот. Выдает  ошибки в реализации слота. Реализация mainclass

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "mainclass.h"
#include <QTextCodec>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

MainClass::MainClass(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent) {

    QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("cp1251"));
    QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("cp1251"));
    QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("cp1251"));

    connect (RunChBox,SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), SLOT(CheckBoxChecked()));
    connect (rawsSpin,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), SLOT(CheckBoxChecked()));
    connect (timer, SIGNAL (timeout()), SLOT(CheckBoxChecked()));

    tEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
    tEdit->resize (300, 300);
    tEdit->setText("Строка перемещается по полю");

    timer = new QTimer (this);

    QHBoxLayout *HLay = new QHBoxLayout (this);
    QGroupBox *SG = new QGroupBox (this);
    QVBoxLayout *VLay = new QVBoxLayout;

    RunChBox = new QCheckBox (this);
    RunChBox->setText("Запуск");
    colsSpin = new QSpinBox (this);
    colsSpin->setRange(0, 6);
    colsSpin->setSingleStep(1);

    VLay->addWidget(RunChBox);
    VLay->addWidget(colsSpin);
    this->setLayout(HLay);
    SG->setGeometry(300,0,100,100);
    SG->setLayout(VLay);
}

MainClass::~MainClass()
{   
}

void MainClass::CheckBoxChecked() {

    timer->setInterval(1000);
    int V = rawsSpin->value();

    while (RunChBox->isChecked()) {
        timer->start();
        --V;
        if (V > 0) {
            for(int i = 1; i<rawsSpin->value(); i++) {
                const QString str = tEdit->copy()+"/r/n";
                tEdit->setText(str);
            };
            for (int i = 1; i<rawsSpin->value(); i++) {
                QString str = tEdit->copy();
                QStringList str2 = str.split('/r/n');
                QString res =str2.at(1);
                tEdit->setText(&res);
            }
        }
        else {
            timer->stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибки:

> void value not ignored as it ought to be 57 строка
>
> conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'QString' requested 61 
>   строка
>
> no matching function for call to 'QTextEdit::setText(QString*)' 64 строка

Как их исправить?

Так, ошибки исправил. Компилятор больше не ругается. Но программа неожиданно завершается. [Вопрос на эту тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962964/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-qt-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F)

Comment: tEdit->setText(&res) не надо &

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Несколько моментов:

**1.** Метод [`QTextEdit::copy()`](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtextedit.html#copy) возвращает `void`. Соответственно строка

```
const QString str = tEdit->copy() + "/r/n";
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

превратится в

```
const QString str = void + "/r/n";
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Вот Вам и

> void value not ignored as it ought to be 57 строка

потому что Вы пытаетесь `void` сложить с `const char *`.

---

**2.** Во втором цикле похожая проблема, только там без сложения.

```
QString str = tEdit->copy();
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Что равносильно:

```
QString str = void;
              ^^^^
```

Поэтому компилятор и ругается на преобразования:

> conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'QString' requested 61 строка.

---

**3.** Метод [`QTextEdit::setText(const QString &text)`](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtextedit.html#setText) ожидает ссылку на `QString`, а Вы пытаетесь передать указатель.

**В итоге**: думаю, Вам больше подойдет метод [`QTextEdit::toPlainText()`](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtextedit.html#toPlainText) вместо `QTextEdit::copy()` (посмотрите в документации, `copy` копирует строку в буфер обмена, а не возвращает строку.. Судя по коду, Вам нужен именно метод, возвращающий строку).

Замените `copy` на `toPlainText`, и уберите `&` в строке:

```
tEdit->setText(&res);
```

Comment: Мне пишет, что у QTextEdit нет метода text() ошибку с res исправил

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, исправил.. Правильно `toPlainText`.

Comment: Так, ошибки исправил. Компилятор больше не ругается. Но программа неожиданно завершается.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, ну, это уже тема для другого вопроса :) Вы ведь спрашивали про ошибки компилятора.

Comment: хорошо, сейчас перезадам.

Comment: Задал новый вопрос